# DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm trying to split a Dataframe into 2 columns based on the ";".

I import my data that looks like this:

When I import it, I got a (555,1) DataFrame.

```
xEUR--------;
CH_USD      ;001.1814
CH_GBP      ;000.8534
CH_CHF      ;001.0831
CH_JPY      ;130.3900
CAC DIVISOR ;230.4093
PXA         ;6558.4680
CAC INDEX   ;6558.4680
CAC   JUIN21;6681.2714
CAC   JUIL21;6558.2077
CAC   AOUT21;6554.8335
CAC   SEPT21;6550.8098

def get_px():
px_brice2 = pd.read_csv(Filename['px'], header=None)
px_brice2 = px_brice2.str.split(';', expand=True)
```

But I have the following error: "DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'"
Could you please help me creating two columns?

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards

Comment: `str` only applies on Series, your `px_bprice2` is a DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just pass the read_csv method the sep(erator) paramter:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

```
px_brice2 = pd.read_csv(Filename['px'], sep=";", header=None)
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer, I already tried doing it but got the following error : 
"Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 243, saw 3"

Comment: @HugoLny sounds like there's two `;` separators on line 243, might want to have a look at that.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for your help, I'll check :)